# Alternative to $.load() not using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications

I am developing a webapp that is fully utilizing HTML5 Offline/Application Cache, which works really well except for one sticking point...

I use the `$.load()` function to load content when switching between pages. The files I'm loading are files on the same server, however because `$.load` uses `$.ajax` internally, these files are not fetched from the AppCache (the call simply fails).

```
var newPage = $('#slider').append('<div id="'+name+'">');
$('#'+name).load(someurl, function() {
    // Display the loaded content
```

(Note: `someurl` represents a file that does already exist in the AppCache, but just isn't loaded using the above code)

Does anyone know of an alternative to `$.load` that I can use to read .html files that contain javascript that will work when offline?

Ideally, this would be a simply drop in replacement for `$.load`, to load content from one file into a node.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting cache to true in ajax settings.

```
var newPage = $('#slider').append('<div id="'+name+'">');
$.ajaxSetup( {cache:true});
$('#'+name).load(someurl, function() {
    // Display the loaded content
```